# Posterior distribution based on the conjugate Gaussian-gamma prior: Exercise 2.44 from Bishop's book

Tags: machine-learning, probability, self-study, distributions

I have a question on hand from Bishop's book, namely, Problem# 2.44. I describe it below for the convenience. I understand that there might be several questions along these lines, e.g., I found [[1]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30670/posterior-derivation-with-prior-as-normal-gamma-distribution?rq=1). But I would also like to share my attempt utilizing Bishop's notation as much as possible and also I am at a beginner's level. I am not sure whether I am on the right path and will be happy to receive your expert feedback.

*Problem# 2.44*:
Consider a univariate Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}\left(x\mid\mu,\tau^{−1}\right)$ having conjugate Gaussian-gamma prior given by (2.154), i.e., $\mathcal{N}\left(x\mid\mu_0,(\beta\tau)^{-1}\right) \mbox{Gam}\left(\tau\mid a,b\right)$ (*assuming precision* $\tau=\lambda$ *in his (2.154), correct?*) and a data set $\mathbf{x} = \left\{x_1, \cdots , x_N\right\}$ of i.i.d. observations. Show that the posterior distribution is also a Gaussian-gamma distribution of the same functional form as the prior, and write down expressions for the parameters of this posterior distribution.

---

My partial attempt is given below. Now, I am bit stuck and not sure how to show that the posterior is of similar form as the conjugate prior. I would highly appreciate if you can help me to understand this problem.

The joint posterior distribution on $\mu$ and $\tau$  given the observations can be described as following according to Bayes' rule:
\begin{align}
p(\mu, \tau\mid \mathbf{x}) 
&=  \frac{ \underbrace{p(\mathbf{x} \mid \mu, \tau)}_{\text{likelihood}} \ \underbrace{p(\mu, \tau)}_{\text{prior}}}{p(\mathbf{x})} \\
&\propto p(\mathbf{x} \mid \mu, \tau) \ p(\mu, \tau).
\end{align}

The prior is Gaussian-gamma according to the problem, i.e., $\mathcal{N}\left(x\mid\mu_0,(\beta\tau)^{-1}\right) \mbox{Gam}\left(\tau\mid a,b \right)$, such that
\begin{align}
p(\mu, \tau) 
&\propto \tau^{a-1} \exp\left\{ -b \tau\right\} \ \ \left(\frac{\beta\tau}{2\pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \exp\left\{ -\frac{(\beta\tau)}{2} \left( \mu -\mu_0\right)^2 \right\} \\
&\propto  \tau^{a-\frac{1}{2}} \ \exp\left\{ -\frac{\tau}{2} \left[2b + \beta \left( \mu^2 + \mu_0^2 -2\mu\mu_0\right) \right] \right\} \\
&= \tau^{a-\frac{1}{2}} \ \exp\left\{ -\frac{\tau}{2} \left[ \beta  \mu^2   -2\mu \beta \mu_0 + \left(\beta \mu_0^2 + 2b\right) \right] \right\}
\end{align}

The likelihood can be shown as
\begin{align}
p(\mathbf{x} \mid \mu, \tau) 
&= \prod_{n=1}^N p(x_n \mid \mu, \tau) \\
& \propto \prod_{n=1}^{N} \left(\frac{\tau}{2\pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}  \exp\left\{  -\frac{\tau}{2} \left( x_n -\mu\right)^2  \right\} \\
& =  \left(\frac{\tau}{2\pi}\right)^{\frac{N}{2}}  \exp\left\{  -\frac{\tau}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \left( x_n -\mu\right)^2  \right\} \\
&\propto  \tau^{\frac{N}{2}} \exp\left\{  -\frac{\tau}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \left( x_n^2 + \mu^2 - 2x_n \mu\right)  \right\} \\
&= \tau^{\frac{N}{2}} \exp\left\{  -\frac{\tau}{2} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n^2 + \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{N} \mu^2}_{ = N \mu^2} - 2\mu \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n}_{ \overset{\Delta}{=} N \mu_{\rm{ML}}} \right)  \right\} .
\end{align}

So, the joint posterior distribution on $\mu$ and $\tau$ reads:
\begin{align}
p(\mu, \tau\mid \mathbf{x}) 
\propto {} & p(\mathbf{x} \mid \mu, \tau) \ p(\mu, \tau) \\
= {} & \tau^{a-\frac{1}{2}} \ \exp\left\{ -\frac{\tau}{2} \left[ \beta  \mu^2   -2\beta \mu  \mu_0 + \left(\beta \mu_0^2 + 2b\right) \right] \right\}  \\ 
&\times \tau^{\frac{N}{2}} \exp\left\{  -\frac{\tau}{2} \left( N \mu^2  - 2N\mu \mu_{\rm{ML}} + \sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n^2 \right)  \right\} \\
= {} & \tau^{\frac{2a + N + 1}{2} - 1} \ \exp\left\{ -\frac{\tau}{2} \left[ \left(\beta + N\right)  \mu^2 - 2\mu  \left(\beta \mu_0 + N \mu_{\rm{ML}}\right)   + \left( \beta \mu_0^2 + 2b + \sum_{n=1}^N x_n^2 \right) \right]\right\}  . 
\end{align}

Now, I am not sure how to represent it in the nice Gaussian-gamma form. Can you please help? Thank you so much in advance.